# How to use generic classes in Matlab (MIJ package/Miji)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, converters, imagej, java-package

does anyone know how to use generic classes in Matlab using the MIJ package?

every time I tried to use a generic class I get an "Undefined class" error, while other classes gave me no problems. In particular I would like to use an instance of the ComplexRealFloatConverter class from the imglib2 library to get the real values of an FFT.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a path problem, i.e. you need to add the path to the package for example with [`javaaddpath()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html).

For an extensive explanation on how to do that, please read [Bringing Java Classes into MATLAB Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html). The explanation contains how to [make entire packages available](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html#f32458).